# Function of modulus value

Tags: functions, absolute-value

If $f(x)=|x+2|$ and $g(x)=2|x|$, then it is true that $\frac{f(x)+g(x)-|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}=Min(f(x),g(x))$, How do we prove it.

Comment: take cases when $f(x)\ge g(x)$ and $g(x)\ge f(x)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is always true, you can check that :

if $f\leq g$, then :
$$ \frac{f+g-|f-g|}{2}=\frac{f+g-(g-f)}{2}=f$$
Then, if $g\leq$ f :
$$\frac{f+g-|f-g|}{2}=\frac{f+g-(f-g)}{2}=g $$

So you get that :
$$\frac{f+g-|f-g|}{2}=\min(f,g) $$